# JQuery Check All link only occurs once

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I have the following code. It seems to work as it will check all of the boxes and will then uncheck them. However, after the first round, it stops checking and unchecking. It will only check once and uncheck once for all of the check boxes. Afterwards, I only the hyperlinks toggles show and hides.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function selectAll(){
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
          $(this).attr('checked', true);
        });
        $("#select_all").hide();
        $("#unselect_all").show();
      }

      function unselectAll(){
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
          $(this).attr('checked', false);
        });
        $("#select_all").show();
        $("#unselect_all").hide();
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Side note: I recommend using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: No side note. That worked. Post as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: jsfiddle the fastest way to solve ?

Comment: @wm.p1us hard to use jsfiddle on this if I didn't know what was wrong. :)

Comment: attr() is depricated in 1.6,if you are using jquery version < 1.6 attr is fine,for jquery > 1.6 use prop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function selectAll(){
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
          $(this).prop('checked', true);
        });
        $("#select_all").hide();
        $("#unselect_all").show();
      }

      function unselectAll(){
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
        $("#select_all").show();
        $("#unselect_all").hide();
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `prop()` instead of `attr()` as `attr()` give unexpected results when used with checked property, You do not need to use `each()` here, also assign some `class` to group the checkboxes instead of applying to all the checkboxes on page. You can use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to select checkboxes (elements) with same `class`.

```
 function selectAll(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);
    $("#select_all").hide();
    $("#unselect_all").show();
  }

  function unselectAll(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
    $("#select_all").show();
    $("#unselect_all").hide();
  }
```